# UnExpected behavior in Q.nfcall and Q.defer for mongoose mongodb model.save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, q

I am trying to make my mongoose model saves async using Q promises.
I am seeing a difference in behavior of the result object passed in to my promise when I use Q.nfcall or wire up using Q.defer()

Notably, when using Q.defer(), I am able to access all the properties of the result object, just like using the native callback function.
However, when using Q.nfcall, all the properties are undefined.
Even more puzzling, logging both the objects, I can see the entire json string printed out.

This is the code (in coffeescript)

```
Customer = new models.Customer({name: 'John Doe'})
console.log 'Customer.id' + Customer.id

deferred = Q.defer()
Customer.save((error, value) -> 
  deferred.resolve(value)
)

deferred.promise.then((customer) -> 
  console.log 'Deferred::customer.id: ' + customer.id
  console.log 'Deferred::customer.name: ' + customer.name
  console.log 'Deferred::customer: ' + customer)

Q.nfcall(Customer.save.bind(Customer)).then((customer) ->  
  console.log 'Qnfcall::customer.id: ' + customer.id
  console.log 'Qnfcall::customer.name: ' + customer.name
  console.log 'Deferred::customer: ' + customer)
```

This is the output

```
Qnfcall::customer.id: undefined
Qnfcall::customer.name: undefined
Qnfcall::customer: { __v: 0, name: 'John Doe', _id: 54461d5523867cc087ef4374 },0
Deferred::customer.id: 54461d5523867cc087ef4374
Deferred::customer.name: John Doe
Deferred::customer: { __v: 0, name: 'John Doe', _id: 54461d5523867cc087ef4374 }
```

I do not see what I am doing wrong here. Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save), it appears `Model#save`'s callback has three parameters: the error, the saved object, and the number of updated rows:

> The callback will receive three parameters, err if an error occurred, product which is the saved product, and numberAffected which will be 1 when the document was found and updated in the database, otherwise 0.

`Q.nfcall` detects the third parameter to the callback, and resolves the promise with an array `[savedObject, numberAffected]` so that you don't lose the `numberAffected`. See [Q docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks):

> Note that if a Node.js-style API calls back with more than one non-error parameter (e.g. child_process.execFile), Q packages these into an array as the promise's fulfillment value when doing the translation.

In CoffeeScript you could use a destructuring parameter to unpack this array:

```
Q.nfcall(Customer.save.bind(Customer)).then ([customer, rowsAffected]) ->  
  console.log 'Qnfcall::customer.id: ' + customer.id
  console.log 'Qnfcall::customer.name: ' + customer.name
  console.log 'Qnfcall::customer: ' + customer
  console.log 'Qnfcall::rowsAffected: ' + rowsAffected
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. You are right, I missed out on that part of Q's documentation. This fixes it!